# Meteor.call is returning Error invoking Method 'addToMenu': Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor and am trying to use a Meteor.call() to push an object to an array in my collection. Here is my code.

My template events map

```
'click .save': function (event, template) {
var mealId = Session.get('selected');
var category = template.find(".category").value;
var dish = template.find(".dish").value;
 if (category.length && dish.length) {
  addToMenu({
    category: category,
    dish: dish
  });
```

and my model.js in the shared folder,

```
addToMenu = function(options) {
var id = Random.id();
Meteor.call('addToMenu',_.extend({ _id: id}, options));
return id;
};

Meteor.methods({
createMeal: function(options) {
check(options, {
  date: String,
  time: String,
  street: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zipcode: String,
  _id: Match.Optional(String)
});

if (options.street.length > 100)
  throw new Meteor.Error(413, 'Street address too long');
if (options.city.length > 25)
  throw new Meteor.Error(413, 'City name too long');
if (options.state.length > 20)
  throw new Meteor.Error(413, 'State name too long');
if (! this.userId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You must be logged in');

var id = options.id || Random.id();
Meals.insert({
  _id: id,
  owner: this.userId,
  street: options.street,
  city: options.city,
  state: options.state,
  zipcode: options.zipcode,
  date: options.date,
  time: options.time,
  menu: [],
  ingredients: [],
  invited: [],
  rsvps: []
});
return id;
},



addToMenu: function(options) {
check(options, {
  category: String,
  dish: String,
  _id: Match.Optional(String)
});
if (! this.userId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must be logged in to add dishes.");
if (! mealId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(404, "No such meal");
Meals.update(mealId, {$addToSet: {menu: {category: options.category, dish:
options.dish}}});
},
```

I could have just created a related collection called Menu and set {owner: mealId} but I really wanted to run this exercise of embedded documents on MongoDB.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get on your server side console when you try this?

Comment: It says mealId is not defined.  Didn't even think to look at the server console. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that there's no `mealId` variable in scope in the `addToMenu` method. You probably meant to pass it as a parameter:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addToMenu: function(mealId, options) {
    check(mealId, String);
    // rest of function body unchanged
  }
});

addToMenu = function(mealId, options) {
  var id = Random.id();
  Meteor.call('addToMenu', mealId, _.extend({ _id: id}, options));
  return id;
};

'click .save': function (event, template) {
  var mealId = Session.get('selected');
  var category = template.find(".category").value;
  var dish = template.find(".dish").value;
  if (category.length && dish.length) {
    addToMenu(mealId, {category: category, dish: dish});
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for looking I greatly appreciate it.